# Will the community considering making the question edit area wider by hiding the "how to ask"/"formatting help" part or modalize them?

Tags: feature-request, editor

I often find the question editor area too narrow(and not so high, too).

[image]

I know I can make it bigger by dragging the handler below, but there is no way to make it wider. I say this because when editing long lines of code, or more specifically, log lines, the extra wraps will make the post very long and difficult to visualize, when I go back and forth editing. For example, when I edit my last question, I will see paragraphs like:

[image]

We programmers like to fiddle things, customize, and make it comfortable to use. I know the content is pasted in, but it is hard to see clear and I just wonder why the textarea is not expansible horizontally.

I am thinking about why we have the "how to format" or "formatting help" yellow dialog so big and not possible to hide. At least for good/high reputation users?

Comment: You shouldn't piggy back extra questions on your main question. Your additional question about triple-backtick syntax makes this a [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260543/triple-backticks-for-code-blocks-like-github-flavored-markdown), and your question about language-specific syntax hilighting is [also a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints).

Comment: OK second question deleted. Now I know it is not permitted here. Hope someone withdraw their vote-down? But I really, really doubt it. I know ppl love vote-down here in meta. :) at least only a close vote till now.

Comment: @WesternGun "_[On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)_".

Comment: RE: Your update, the line of text in your question is 827 characters long. That's an extreme outlier, and it doesn't really matter whether you're allowed to hide the "formatting help" box to expand the editor, you cannot practically fit that on one line.

Comment: That's correct that the long line can never fit in one line in any editor, but when editing, if possible, I want the editor to be able to resemble the view I can see in a code editor a little more by enabling line length adjustment. Something like that.

Comment: Then it seems like what you really want is to turn off line wrapping, so the editor scrolls horizontally, which isn't really the same thing as making the editor's width resizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can make it bigger by dragging the handler below, but there is no way to make it wider.

I can't think of a good reason to make it wider, and you haven't really provided a good argument for doing so. It's as wide as the content region containing the post, and regardless the width doesn't matter as you're editing text that will dynamically wrap to the width of its container. In other words, the width of the editor doesn't really inform what the results will look like.

It's generally accepted that long lines of text (at least in English) are harder to read, so again, I can't think of a good reason for this.

Conversely, we really want people to notice the yellow box, so keeping it relatively large is desirable.

> By the way, why the code part of editor not using three back tildes for code?

Because that's a non-standard Github extension to markdown, and the editor that Stack Overflow uses is compliant with the standard.

> we can mark the language after the first three tildes, to enable its syntax coloring, like:

You can already do this on Stack Overflow: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Although I have deleted the second question, thanks for the link, very helpful. For the first one, I think at least a standard-like, 2-dimentional-expansible, floating-over-the-big-yellow-dialog-although-not-completely textarea in the editor could be provided.

Comment: OK now at least I get a rough idea how the community thinks.