# Change the code block button from inserting indentation to triple-backticks

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

Working with indentation as formatting is a very annoying experience and it's clear that new users have a problem with it. Also, [many users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260543/triple-backticks-for-code-blocks-like-github-flavored-markdown) seem to be in [support for triple-backticks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260541/6486738).

There are many reasons for it to be the default.

###### You cannot hint the language with indented code blocks as easily as with triple-backticks.

There are questions that require code blocks in multiple languages, which is very easy and straight-forward with triple-backticks, by adding the language just after the ticks e.g. ```` ```rust ```` or ```` ```python ````.

```rust
pub fn main() {}
```

```python
def main(): pass
```

With indented code blocks you have to rely on somewhat obscure and [deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/395477) HTML inlining, e.g. <!-- language: rust --> or <!-- language: python -->.

###### You cannot easily put two code blocks after each other

If you have one indented code block directly followed by another code block, they'll be merged into one. This makes the example I showed above confusing (along with wrong highlighting):

```
pub fn main() {}

def main(): pass
```

###### If you indent your code properly but accidentally forget an empty line in-between the text and the code, it'll not work.

When you get told that the code needs to be indented in order to be formatted as a code block, it can be a bit annoying and confusing when there are these additional rules.

This is text.
This is indented text one line below.

This is text.

```
This is indented text two lines below.
```

###### It's slightly more annoying to insert code in an already existing code block.

Since I can't insert with tab, I'll have to insert with 4 spaces. If the code is indented, then I have to spam 4 extra spaces for every line I want to insert. And if I want to break up the code in two lines I'll have to make sure to indent the other line also to not mess up the formatting.

###### Backticks are what is used in the comments.

This will give more consistency and hint people on how to format code in the comment section.

---

Overall, the triple-backtick option is more convenient and easier for many people, and I think that it would be beneficial for many new users to properly format their code and for editors to fix bad formatting. Therefore, it should be the preferred default when using the GUI button or using the hotkey to create code sample.

Comment: [Cross site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter/354572#354572) stating that indent is [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]]

Comment: I would say significant percent of new users have some troubles with code formatting, so

Comment: ^ so the question would then be why? Are the instructions for code formatting not clear enough? Not readily available (where a new user would see them)? Something else?

Comment: "You cannot hint the language with indented code blocks like you can with triple-backtick." - you can, but apparently it's deprecated now and may be removed. You have to put a `<!-- language: lang-whatever -->` comment before the code block. See the footnote in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: *"Are the instructions for code formatting not clear enough? "* I think it's that that users don't take the effort to format... Not that they don't make the effort to put their code in code blocks/fences. I frequently see questions that are full of huge blocks of text and single lines of code that are 400 characters long. Unfortunately switching from indent to fences by default isn't going to fix the root problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yeah, that's one solution but it's not really equivalent as it's applying the hint to *all* code blocks. This is the same effect you get from tagging the question with the language. And if you use it to override the default syntax highlighting for a code block, all subsequent blocks will be highlighted with the new language hint. So while it does work (until they remove it), the usage is much more involved.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: No, you're thinking of the very similar, not deprecated `<!-- language-all: lang-whatever -->` syntax. The form without the `-all` only applies to one code block.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh, you're right. I tried out the tag in the footnote and didn't notice the `-all`. Thanks, good to know there is a way!

Comment: So, basically, we should just remove indentation formatting altogether, because (as far as I can tell) it offers no benefits over using triple-backticks, and in fact is less intuitive. On the downside, if we remove it, then all the posts that already have indentation formatting are going to look much worse. So why did we have indentation formatting at all? _Especially_ since the Stack Overflow post-editing textboxes don't have an indent feature, requiring the user to either indent their code in an editor or manually insert 4 spaces on _each... individual... line..._

Comment: The one and only good thing I can think of for having that button indent a block of code is for the not-so-common case of putting a code block inside a bulleted/numbered list. I find the easiest way to format it properly (the code to be aligned with the indentation of the bullet) is to first wrap the code with backticks and then mark the code ***including the backticks*** and press the code-format button to indent the whole thing to be under the list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good point! I never actually used it for that, I guess because my lists aren't that long. In fact, I don't really use the buttons at all, except for inserting images. But again, this all seems to be pointing to the need for an indentation feature that isn't necessarily a code-formatting feature. Maybe we could have a shortcut for indentation, like the `Ctrl+[` and `Ctrl+]` shortcuts that VSCode uses.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin There already is `ctrl+k`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo True, but that's just for little inline code blocks, and it doesn't have indentation. Or do you mean that it wouldn't be hard to add another shortcut, because they already have some?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin No, we already have shortcut for indentation. Highlight a multiline block of code, press `ctrl+k` and it will all be indented 4 spaces

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh. I never knew that either. But it only ever goes 4 spaces. If we wanted multiple levels of indentation, we would still be required to use an external editor. I think that the `Ctrl+K` shortcut is designed for code-formatting, not indentation alone, because as well as indenting the code, it inserts new lines at the top and bottom of the selection, which would be required because of reason 2 in the question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260541/3195477

Comment: @SylvesterKruin To get multiple levels of indentation, you can successively select and indent just the lines which need the additional indentation, even adding fake lines if needed (and removing after indenting) to get a larger indent. For example: you want a group of lines at a 12 space indent to be at 16: add a 0 space indented single character line prior to them, select that 0 space line and all the others and hit ctrl-k, then delete the now 4 space indented line). It's not great, but it does work and is a reasonable way to accomplish some quick formatting; also works for unindenting.

Comment: Personally, id much rather a feature to ban users who don't format their code, period.

Comment: I still remember coming to SO from posting on forums and other places years and years ago, I found the "indent for code" thing very confusing. Even after I got used to it, I found it inconvenient, and hard to read. Using triple backticks would not suddenly make pasting code painless (posters would still have to remove indents that were present due to class/namespace/etc. blocks in e.g., C#) but at least I can clearly see where the code starts and ends with triple backticks. SO actually taught me markdown, funny enough.

Comment: I love how this kind of question needs to be asked every N months and yet nobody on the dev team seems to care. Not a single feature in the text current editor that makes it even slightly decent for writing code: no auto-indentation, tab makes you select the next item in the page, no indent/dedent functionality... it's hell. When I edit posts for other people, I have to copy/paste the code into VSCode, edit it and then copy-paste it back. You know how many edits I would have been willing to make if it weren't for the awful UX of the editor? Double the amount I did, probably.

Comment: I'd rather keep the `{}` UI button as an indent/unindent, as that's a *much* more involved operation, and *much* more work to do by hand, when needed. Adding code fences using backticks is *trivial* to do by hand. All you have to do is hit the ` key six times and put each of the two sets of three on separate lines. Why expend a UI button to do something that's so trivial to do by hand?

Comment: Aside from all other considerations, when I am editing the posts of (mostly) new users, I find it *vastly* easier to get them into shape when they have used backpacks rather than indents.

Comment: @Makyen because a lot of new users are not familiar with Markdown (and backticks are **not** trivial at all to do on some keyboards). It’s also "trivial" to put text in bold or italics, and still we have these buttons. Is there a use-case for indentation outside of formatting code? If not, there’s no point of keeping a button for that if we encourage the use of backticks.

Comment: Code snippets on SO use the old format, in case someone forgets about them.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin for the most part, properly indenting code in their own machine before posting it to a question *is* an expectation of the question asker.

Comment: I would like for them to add indent/unindent buttons to the editor that let us just add/remove 4 spaces from a selection an unlimited number of times.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm with you. For a site that started as a programmers resource, support for programming is surprisingly shabby.

Comment: It has become a common formatting feature in many communication tools, including Slack and even Teams, to use markdown-style triple indentation, and it would be a great improvement to support it on SO.

Comment: @bfontaine Out of curiosity, what keyboard doesn't have the backtick? Is it the Mac keyboard? My laptop is a humble HP, but it still has a backtick/tilde key.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli YES!! I've been wondering that for quite a while now. People are obviously complaining about things that obviously need changing, but the developers don't seem to notice. I understand it often takes a while to go through the whole code-writing, testing, deployment etc. process, but couldn't they at least let us know they're doing something? And here we have the developers working on things that did _not_ need the "improvement" they got, case in point the new profile design.

Comment: That is a fair point that SO's actual code editor is pretty terrible. I think the only modern thing worse than it is vanilla notepad.exe. I would consider the ability to easily remove / add indents to a selected block to be the bare minimum for any serious editor and SO does not clear that bar. The workflow is to fidget with the code in a more capable editor to get it in the format SO likes (almost literally anything else) and then paste it, which is pretty silly UX. With such a primitive editor it's not that surprising there's so many formatting problems Also the editor is thin with word wrap

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I’ve seen a lot of French junior developers having trouble with it. It’s present on the azerty French layout but it needs a modifier key so even if you know where it is you still have to either put your right hand in a weird position or use your two hands to do it.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin A lack of dog fooding I think. The people making decisions don't use Stack Overflow (maybe in any way at all), they're speculating on what the user experience is like instead of actually using it. SE inc.'s org is well "protected" from success on a QA platform (too many layers between boss and dev users), so much so that that they are now going to just try and survive on brand recognition (which is for sale; use SO branding to push <customer> branding). I have no idea why they keep redoing profile pages; who is the customer? I would be confused as a designer working at SO.

Comment: @jrh Yeah, that makes sense. I guess I shouldn't blame the developers; I should blame the people (between boss and developers) who are telling them what needs to change without actually knowing what needs to change.

Comment: 4-Space_Indent is "Okay"  for up to 3 Lines of Code, more than that, it should be Backtick_x3... The only "Advantage" I find otherwise to the 4-Space_Indent, is that I "directly" know when Users post on my "small" Tech Forum that they also opened a parallel Thread on SO and they usually get "mad" when I ask them to "maintain the same Quality" on both Forums/Sites if they want me to answer their Thread, ah-ah...! (And the Quality I strive for on "my" Forum is much-much higher than here on SO, oops...!)

Comment: "I think it's that that users don't take the effort to format... Not that they don't make the effort to put their code in code blocks/fences." That said, fences are much easier to implement manually.

Comment: I think everyone should use code fences... and spaces, not tabs! *runs away, laughing maniacally*.

Comment: Two years have passed and this issue is still very relevant. Every third newcomer just can't get their code formatting right because the editor is highly unintuitive.

Comment: and there is me who only wish my local keyboard has an easy way to type backticks. *sigh*

Comment: It's been more than a year and indentation is still the default. _sigh_ Indentation is so fiddly, especially when combined with `>`.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Absolutely. Fenced code blocks are a dramatic UX improvement.

- The extra indentation makes editing an existing block much harder.
- Fenced blocks make the process of copy/pasting code into the question trivial. You don't need to edit the code after pasting it. It is common to paste from an actual compilable/executable source file.
- Indentation is also used with lists (bullet and numbered), making it more confusing how to properly indent a block inside them. Fenced blocks provide a separate syntax, simplifying the markup for indenting a block inside a list.

I'm sure I could come up with more, but those are issues I encountered *all the time* when I was active. Indented code blocks are annoying.

Comment: *"Fenced code blocks are a dramatic UX improvement."* - Be prepared that [not everyone shares this sentiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409009/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable I can only see one commenter there suggesting that there are a few edge cases where indenting is useful, namely when discussing Markdown itself. Most of the discussion is about how useful it is to _edit existing posts_ to switch styles, which isn't relevant here.

Comment: @ims The title of the question is *"What is the preferred method for formatting code?"*. I was answering *that* question (not whether the alleged *mass editing* that were to ensue, inevitably, were desirable). That answer has just about as many upvotes as it has downvotes.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, I didn't look at the votes, only the comments, so I didn't understand what you were linking to.

Comment: @IInspectable That answer is not only about fenced code blocks, but also two other issues: *changing that in edits*, and how to fence blocks and those might have caused the downvote. As noted one major problem with backtick is that it is complicated to type on many keyboards, which makes it hard to do it manually - but that is not an issue for the code-block button.

Comment: @IInspectable From the comments it seems clear that at least *some* (if not all!) of the downvotes are from people who don’t agree that editing a post solely to change the code fence style is appropriate. The downvotes say nothing about whether people actually prefer indentation, and it’s highly unlikely that a significant number do.

Comment: @kon Voting is anonymous. It's opaque to me how you derive your conclusions given that there is no data available. This reads like opinion delivered as if it was a fact.

Comment: The biggest problem with _fenced code_ on pasting is that most of us are pasting from heavily indented sources. I personally fix my indenting in the IDE before I paste into SO but its clear that a lot of people do not do this, so _fencing_ makes it even more important that we provide keyboard or toolbar support for indenting blocks.

Comment: BTW, you can also use triple tilde `~~~` for code fences, which may be easier than triple backticks on some keyboards. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/4014959

Comment: @IInspectable If we can't glean any meaning from voting and the context surrounding it, then neither can you. You cannot use downvotes on your answer to defend the notion that some users prefer indented blocks and simultaneously dismiss Konrad's analysis of their meaning based on the context. That would be blatant hypocrisy.

Comment: @jpm Votes do carry meaning, obviously. There's a difference between using that raw data, and guessing at how that data came about. I used the raw data, when Konrad was playing the speculation game. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @IInspectable Raw data would be, "There are 13 downvotes on this answer." Claiming those downvotes represent a preference for indented code blocks is "guessing at how that data came about," or more succinctly, an interpretation. Can *you* see the difference? Konrad was examining additional data that suggested a different interpretation (namely, what objections were actually raised in comments by potential downvoters), not speculating.

Comment: @jpm I was never claiming any of that. Read my comment again, and stick to what I **did** say. Not what you would have liked me to have claimed just so that you can prove me wrong.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller But indented code has the *exact same* issue, unless all your real code is somehow magically indented by exactly four spaces.

Comment: How do you include fenced code blocks in list items?

Comment: @sta The normal indentation rules for [nesting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) in lists apply.

Comment: @stackprotector You leave a blank line after the list item (the line starting with `*` or `1.`) and then indent the entire block (including the back-ticks themselves) by 4 spaces. (You can also have multiple nested paragraphs under the same list item. You just need a blank line and indentation for each one.)

Comment: @IInspectable "I was answering that question" - and your answer appears to come out strongly in favour of fences? You seem to imply that you don't share the opinion that they're a "dramatic UX improvement", but I don't see how the answer you've linked actually argues against that.

Comment: @stackprotector [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45075450/1394393) (the "Compute according to probabilities" section)

Answer (score 59):

I agree.

One of the biggest annoyances I face is reviewing edits from new users who have added code fences to indented code without removing the first layer of indentation.

Code like this:

```
const myVar = "Hello"
const message = myVar + " friends!"
alert(message)
```

Becomes:

```js
    const myVar = "Hello"
    const message = myVar + " friends!"
    alert(message)
```

Because <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> don't work in the editor without userscripts, a large number of users don't take the time to fix indentation in their edits.

Comment: Note for any aspiring editors having this problem: the correct solution is to select the code and click the code-format button to strip the existing indent, then add the triple backticks.

Comment: @RyanM: that's the only thing I'd be worried about with a change to the editor for the code-formatting button (and ctrl-k shortcut) to use fences: whether that would leave you without a way to un-indent a block like you might want to in an old post that either shouldn't have used code-formatting at all, or has janky indentation inside the block, or that you're converting to fenced.

Comment: @RyanM but note one should make sure the selection highlight runs all the way to the start of every line; making the selection highlight stop just to the left of the first word in the code makes it go haywire

Comment: @Joundill honestly, I'm just glad when people format with code at all; I couldn't care less how indented it is

Comment: @CaiusJard That's reasonable, for most languages. However, in Python, it's a serious issue because Python uses indentation syntactically to mark block structure (instead of braces). So when an OP posts badly formatted code it can be hard to know if it's merely a formatting error that arose in posting the code, or if it's an actual error in their original source code.

Comment: For a while my edits consisted mainly of pasting the code into https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/20su/indent.html, then pasting it back

Comment: I agree too.⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 30):

I find the original code indentation, though buggy, very useful in cleaning up code that was pasted from inside multiple indentations. If the code button was to be changed to use backticks, then I would suggest that *increase and decrease indent buttons should be added to the toolbar*.

Because the default indentation button would remove the indentation for already indented code, I found it very helpful as a button to decrease indentation in general. In fact I find my self at a block of text/code deliberately manipulating the first line, knowing that the indentation will be applied based on that first line. So when editing code/script answers on my phone I could quickly build the indentation that I was expecting.

Comment: Yes, also do we really need a button for triple backtick indentation? It is so easy to to type, that it is more work fist to select the entire block, and the to use the mouse to press the button.

Comment: @user000001 backticks are not so easy to type on some keyboards, especially if you’re not familiar with them. The first point of a button is not to save you time, but to let you use formatting without being familiar with Markdown.

Comment: Better than adding yet more buttons: handle the Tab key correctly (= as expected), especially when the user has highlighted a block of text. (I know Cmd+k already does that and I use it frequently but it’s at best a sub-par replacement.)

Comment: @bfontaine on a dekstop PC you can use autohotkey to replace a character that is easy to type. On my iPhone i've set ttt to be a shortcut for ``` because it's heck of a lot easier to type and doesn't occur naturally

Comment: An indent button would be useful regardless of what behavior the code block button implements. Indentation is useful in a wide variety of cases, including list mark up and within code blocks. So I'd say this use case is just a justification for indentation functionality, rather than a reason to have the code button perform indents. Indeed, the button currently *does the wrong thing* in cases where indentation is used for something else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Tab already has a defined behavior in browsers (moving focus between elements). I strongly object to overriding browser keyboard shortcuts. It leads to a lot of trouble for heavy keyboard users like myself.

Comment: @jpmc26 I would *generally* agree — except in editors (which this is). Because Tab already has a defined behaviour in editors, and I strongly object to overriding editor keyboard shortcuts (by the browser, as it were). It leads to a lot of trouble for heavy keyboard users like myself (apologies for copying your comment almost verbatim,  but I couldn’t have made the argument better myself).

Comment: @KonradRudolph In browsers, Tab should move from a text box to the next item in the form, often the submission button.

Comment: @jpmc26 As I said: yes (and you don’t need to convince me, I extensively use the keyboard to navigate). Except when the focus is on editors because *Tab has a different, overriding behaviour in editors*. And the focus switching is a trivially solvable issue: just make Esc leave the editor control so that the next Tab press jumps to the next control (this is the expected behaviour for me anyway, and it’s intensely frustrating that browsers don’t seem to behave this way by default).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Whether you find the defaults to be less than ideal is immaterial. The fact is they are there and users are used to them and have developed expectations and usage patterns surrounding them. Overriding them is more of a pain in the butt than dealing with them, because then not only do you need to adjust your usage around the less than ideal parts of browser, but also you have to change your usage for the inconsistent behavior of every single site. It's not worth it.

Comment: @jpmc26 There are *two conflicting defaults here*. You seem to place the defaults of the browser over those of an editor, but I don’t accept that premise. And, given that there is a trivially simple fix to make both defaults work together in harmony, I find your premise entirely backwards. Maybe your disagreeing means just that I haven’t explained my suggestion clearly: I don’t suggest breaking tab-between-controls. Clearly, this *must* continue to work. I am just saying that, if the editor is focused, tab-to-next-control requires pressing Esc first. This is already an established UX pattern.

Comment: It would be much better to have explicit indent and dedent buttons, yes. I would like to be able to indent a selection further that is already indented on every line, and dedent a selection that includes lines that are not indented. You know, like how decent text editors work.

Answer (score 15):

To give something that's been mentioned in comments its own answer to vote on, how about:

- Change the "Code Sample" button to use backtick-style
- Add "Increase Indent" and "Decrease Indent" buttons
- Make sure the order of buttons makes sense - probably "Code Sample", "JS/HTML/CSS Snippet", "Decrease Indent", "Increase Indent" (for some reason, "Image" currently comes in between Sample and Snippet)

Answer (score 10):

### I agree **100%**!

Using indentation for code formatting is very confusing, especially in languages such as Python where indentation is used for control structures. I have seen *many* posts where the formatting was terrible because the user had pasted some code, half of which was indented and half of which wasn't.
That type of issue does not occur with triple backticks. I think limiting code formatting to triple backticks only would be much more intuitive for everyone vs. indentation.

Indentation is a very fragile and annoying method of formatting code.

### Please get the keys right!

<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should indent/deindent instead of jumping out of the editor. This has caused me no end of grief. I know this is possible because I've seen it in editors like [`ace.js`](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> should still format a block as code, but now using triple backticks.

Comment: As I commented on another post, the `tab` key is used for navigation in web browser, changing that breaks accessibility.

Comment: This site exists for the purpose of posting (and _hopefully_ formatting) code. The benefits of making the `Tab` key work for indentation in the editor far outweigh the sacrifice to accessibility.

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, but your second is effectively saying that your ease of use outweighs other people's ease of use? It's a minor inconvenience for you to use a different key combo to indent, where as changing the `tab` functionality can make the page completely non functional for users with certain methods of interaction (Try posting a question without using a mouse and not being able to tab out of the input area)

Comment: The `Tab` key would only need to function differently when the focus is in the editor. I do not believe that people should change their way of interacting with the site just because I prefer it a different way. But I do honestly think there would be more people who find the suggested change beneficial than people who are thrown off by it.

Comment: The issue is that tab is the main way that a keyboard-only (or other accessibility input device) would leave the editor, so by changing it we'd effectively trap users in the input area, making everything after it inaccessible.

Comment: @DBS The issue is that tab is the main way that developers/writers indent content. Changing it would effectively cause the editor to not function as expected and frustrate users, making the entire experience awful.

Comment: @DBS I understand. On the [Ask Question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), a user has to hit `Tab` twice before getting to the editor(once to focus on the title box, once more for the editor). It might make sense to enable the special `Tab` functionality in the editor on a case by case basis, like if the user has _not_ already hit `Tab` twice to get to the editor. This means they are capable and willing to use the mouse, and consequently that they would be able to escape the editor focus without having to use the `Tab` key.

Comment: If they could detect keyboard navigation and disable tab indentation that would be great (and personally, I'd love to be able to tab-indent) I just don't think that's particularly achievable in a reliable way. If only the tab key didn't have two different (yet overlapping) uses...

Comment: I'd prefer to see standard code blocks get the same treatment as code snippets. Edit the code block, sending you to a code editor, (or even just make all code blocks snippets, improve switching to the snippet editor, and have run be a toggle that's off by default)

Comment: @KevinB Now that's an idea! I forgot about code snippets because I never use them since they only work for web code, but adding support for more languages would definitely make sense!

Comment: yeah, basing "run" on the language chosen wouldn't be a bad idea either. better'n a toggle

Comment: @NoahBroyles Different behaviour on a case-by-case basis sounds like a nightmare, to be honest. It’s much simpler to make the Tab key inside the editor have a consistent behaviour (in-/dedent) and only switch to a different control after the user pressed Esc to leave edit mode.

Comment: Just to be really clear for the people making false equivalences: some people **can not use a mouse**, so are **entirely reliant on keyboard navigation**. Breaking the behaviour of the tab key for those people is not a simple inconvenience to be weighed up against the rest of us memorising Ctrl-K. The idea of hitting Escape to exit edit mode makes a lot of sense **if** combined with the idea of combining with a pop-up code editor (like for Snippets), where Escape is a natural navigation key. Otherwise, navigating will be like [exiting vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/157957).

Comment: @IMSoP Frankly, invoking the “exiting vim” trope is a bad-faith argument. Firstly, because it’s a meme, not an argument. And secondly, because pressing Esc in an editor control to make Tab switch to the next control is an established UX pattern, and absolutely not limited to Vim (in fact, Vim *doesn’t* use this pattern).

Comment: @KomradRudolph True, it is a bit of a tired joke, but my point wasn't about Vim's use of Escape in particular, it was about not knowing the special keys for a system - I actually struggle to exit Emacs. So: "pressing Esc in an editor control .. is an established UX pattern" - is it? As I say, if the control is activated as a pop-up of some sort, then escape to *dismiss the pop-up* feels natural to me, but I'm not sure hitting "Escape then Tab" to move on from a normal form field would occur to me. (I'm assuming Escape followed by a letter would just type that letter into the text area?)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thinking about it, rather than inline vs pop-up, the key is the symmetry of entering and exiting: if you have to press Enter to activate the control, then Escape to deactivate it makes sense; if you can get *to* the control with Tab, then not being able to get *past* the field by hitting Tab again would be surprising and frustrating.

Comment: @IMSoP I don’t agree that there’s a prior expectation of symmetry, and it’s certainly not a requirement.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a UI/UX person so this might actually be a terrible idea, but this is my suggestion:

***If/when** the code-block button is changed to insert backticks instead of indents, please **keep the `ctrl+k` shortcut to indent** the highlighted block.*

As I stated [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414860/change-the-code-block-button-from-inserting-indentation-to-triple-backticks?cb=1#comment886181_414860) above, the main reason I see for auto-indents being useful is when adding code to a bulleted list. i.e. this:

> ````
> 1. An example
> ```
> some code
> ```
> ````

Will be rendered as:

> 1. An example
>
> ```
> some code
> ```

But in order for the code to be under the list item it needs to be indented another level. I find it most convenient to use backticks and then highlight the code ***together with the backticks*** and use the indent button. It would become tedious if that button didn't indent anymore but it would be great if I could at least press `ctrl+k` to easily achieve:

> ````
> 1. An example
>     ```
>     some code
>     ```
> ````

which will give:

> 1. An example
>
>    ```
>    some code
>    ```

Comment: I think the suggestions elsewhere of having separate buttons for "increase indent" and "decrease indent" would cover this, assuming anyone knew that was the necessary magic trick. Or of course we could just use a markup language that's less terrible than Markdown 

Comment: I'd rather have `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` do indent/unindent.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I like those settings in an IDE, but repurposing the tab key would cause all sorts of accessibility issues on a webpage.

Comment: Fair point, @DBS. OTOH, I wouldn't mind a dollar for every time someone accidentally tried to indent code in the SO editor using the tab key. ;)

Comment: Apart from the accessibility issue raised above, utilizing the Tab key actually requires the dev team to implement new functionality. What I suggest is literally *"do nothing"* (leave the `ctrl+k` as it is now) which realistically is a lot more likely to happen...

Comment: @IMSoP "Or of course we could just use a markup language that's less terrible than Markdown" - any suggestions?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've heard there's this thing called "HTML", where instead of random punctuation and carefully counted whitespace, everything is formatted with a consistent system of "tags", which can be nested in all sorts of different ways. I don't know if it will ever catch on, though...

Answer (score 5):

The [new editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/2988) – i.e. the one that I am typing this very answer in – *already* does that. The old editor is not going to be changed, since that would only delay development of the new editor.

Comment: But the new editor hasn't been added to the main site yet. It's only on MSO and MSE which isn't very great.

Comment: And both editors screw up quoting & unquoting code blocks.

Comment: While the "new" editor does do this, it has substantial other issues which makes it, *at best*, problematic to use.

Comment: Unfortunately the new editor only adds backtick fences in Markdown mode. when using the button in WYSIWYG mode and then changing to Markdown the code is displayed as indented instead. (It also sometimes adds redundant empty lines around the code but that’s a separate issue …)

Comment: It is my informed opinion that WISYWIG is *awful* for formatting. Always. If a user can't get the editor to insert markup to do what they want, they won't be able to manipulate the formatting with WISYWIG very effectively either. I'd rather trash the new one, frankly.